# After 1st try to save data and cant open after close the program

Tags: java, swing, file

```
public class internetCalculator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

    public internetCalculator() throws IOException {
        initComponents();
        loadDataFromFile();
        jPanel1.hide();
        mainMenuJ.show(true);
    }


    public void saveDataToFile() throws IOException {
        //Below is Internet Plan, D for DIGI, M for Maxis....
        double D = 0.05, M = 0.10, C = 0.02, R1 = 0.12;
        double total = 0, tax = 0; //Plan Tax Rate Per MB
        double normal = 30.0, pro = 45.0, superPro = 65.0, ultra = 90;//Package

        try {
            String name = nameTF.getText();
            String phNo = phNoTF.getText();
            String usage = usageTF.getText();
            String bPlan = planCB.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String bPackage = packageCB.getSelectedItem().toString();

            double internetUsage = Double.parseDouble(usage);

            //First Calculation ***PLAN***
            if (planCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Digi Plan")) {
                total = internetUsage * D;
            } else if (planCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Maxis Plan")) {
                total = internetUsage * M;
            } else if (planCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Celcom Plan")) {
                total = internetUsage * C;
            } else if (planCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Red1 Plan")) {
                total = internetUsage * R1;
            }
            if (packageCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Normal")) {
                tax = total + normal;
            } else if (packageCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Pro")) {
                tax = total + pro;
            } else if (packageCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("SuperPro")) {
                tax = total + superPro;
            } else if (packageCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("UltraHighSpeed")) {
                tax = total + ultra;
            }

            User users = new User(name, phNo, bPlan, bPackage, tax);
            list.add(users); //add object s to array
            File outFile = new File("Internet_Tax.txt");
            FileWriter outFileStream = new FileWriter(outFile, true);
            PrintWriter outStream = new PrintWriter(outFileStream);
            outStream.println(name);
            outStream.println(phNo);
            outStream.println(bPlan);
            outStream.println(bPackage);
            outStream.println(tax);
            outStream.close();

            //If User Didnt Choose any Plan and Package , Display Error
            if ((packageCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select"))
                || (planCB.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select"))) {
                throw new Exception("Please Select PLAN or PACKAGE to Perform Calculation !");
            }

            if (!name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                throw new Exception("Name With Letter with A - Z ONLY !");
            }// name with only Letter
            if (!phNo.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                throw new Exception("Phone Number with DIGIT number ONLY! ");
            }//Phone number only DIGIT
            if (!usage.matches("[0-9]+")) {
                throw new Exception("Internet Usage with DIGIT number ONLY! ");
            }//Internet Usage only DIGIT

        } catch (Exception e) {
            outputTA.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }//End Save Data To File

    public void loadDataFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File inFile = new File("Internet_Tax.txt");

        if (inFile.exists()) {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
            list.clear();
            DefaultTableModel stable = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
            String header[] = new String[]{"Name", "Phone", "Plan","Package","Total_Tax"};
            stable.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
            tableT.setModel(stable);

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String name = scanner.nextLine();
                String phNo = scanner.nextLine();
                String bPlan = scanner.nextLine();
                String bPackage = scanner.nextLine();
                double tax = scanner.nextDouble();
                User users = new User(name, phNo, bPlan, bPackage, tax);
                stable.addRow(new Object[]{name, phNo, bPlan, bPackage, tax});
                list.add(users);

            }

            scanner.close();
            fileReader.close();
            nameTF.setText(""); // name
            phNoTF.setText(""); // matric
            usageTF.setText("");  // Phone
            planCB.setSelectedItem("Select");
            packageCB.setSelectedItem("Select");
        } else {
            DefaultTableModel stable = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
            String header[] = new String[]{"Name", "Phone", "Plan","Package","Total_Tax"};
            stable.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
            tableT.setModel(stable);
        }
}
```

During the first try of running this program, the program seems to run well and display the data in table. After I close the program and run the program again, it displays errors. I don't know what is the error inside my code. The Exception error show on the `loadDataFromFile()`:

[image: Here is the Error message]

Comment: Too much code. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The trouble is with  double tax = scanner.nextDouble(); - try reading into String here as well, Print that string to System.out for visual check and then Double.parseDouble() the value into your tax variable

Comment: Did someone change the file Internet_Tax.txt after your first run?  You sure it didn't change?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky No it didnt.

Comment: @Turing85 actually there mostly of the if else statement is just calculation.. It Can be ignore.

Comment: @Jane But it is double type after done the calculation. Although it is String type in the TextField. So I change it to String Type ?

Comment: Copy the entire stack trace of the error into your question *as text.*  Do not post pictures of text.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem after reducing Internet_Tax.txt to the fewest rows?  I agree with @Jan though, first get the String value of the line and print it out so you know what row is causing the problem.  Does it handle that row correctly the first time you run?

Comment: Please try to adding your scanner method into try catch block and test it.

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky But my User Defined Class is setting the constructor with double type value, so i should change it back to String and try ?
Or it is another way to approach the ComboBox to String ?

Comment: Changing to String is just for debugging.  I want to see what the characters are that it's trying to turn into a double.  More importantly, I want to see if those characters change between the first and second run.

Comment: After i change the dataType of tax to String . Its work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way will show you where is the problem..

Put your scanning codes in to `try catch` and add a condition before getting double value.

For example :

```
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      try {
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        String phNo = scanner.nextLine();
        String bPlan = scanner.nextLine();
        String bPackage = scanner.nextLine();

         if(scanner.hasNextDouble()){
           double tax = scanner.nextDouble();
         }else{System.out.println("Value is not Double!")}

    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("WARNING : " + e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        scanner.close();
        User users = new User(name, phNo, bPlan, bPackage, tax);
        stable.addRow(new Object[]{name, phNo, bPlan, bPackage, tax});
        list.add(users);
   }                    
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I think its is another way out, and I have changed my dataType to String and its work too.